# Is there a way to log entry deletions within EE?

Tags: users

The Control Panel Log doesn't seem to record this type of activity. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Not natively, no. But there are various [extension hooks](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/cp/content_edit/index.html#delete-entries-end) that you can tie into with a custom module to easily log to a file or database table.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Perhaps there is an opportunity here for an add-on? We have a corporate client that has a few 'Editors', each with permissions to add, edit and delete entries. Entries are going missing and it would great to know if it's a user issue.

Comment: Any suggestions on features? I've already written a logging extension for a website of ours that logs deletions, new entries, when statuses are changed from Review -> Open, so if this is the core functionality you're after I'll be happy to push to devote-ee as a free download.

Comment: Wow. Yes, that would be great!

Comment: Features: New Entries, Deleted Entries and Status Changes would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

If this issue is occurring on a frequent/regular basis, you could remove delete privileges from that member group to see if the issue goes away.

If you remove delete privileges, you can still accomplish taking content offline using Status. `status==closed` should disable content from appearing. Typically your editors should not be able to delete anything from the site, for reasons like this. They should have the power to take content off the site, but that's a much different action than a delete.

You could also see if [Better Workflow](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/better-workflow) supports more fine-grained options or the feature you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Mark. This is what I've suggested to the client. Using revisions, I believe we should be able to see who has 'closed' the entry?

Comment: I just did a quick test and confirmed: Yes. Changing status to closed or open is tracked as a revision in the Revisions tab/history. It does not say what was revised, but it does say which user made changed the entry with a timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OmniLog](https://github.com/experience/omnilog.ee_addon) together with custom extension as suggested by Michael.

The Control Panel logging solution is really missing for EE. I have a customer with problems similar to yours and also having hard time figuring out who's causing the problems. I think I will develop something eventually, but that's not my top priority for now.

Comment: Thanks Yuri. Agreed, I think some kind of configurable logging system would be great within EE...certainly for Enterprise level projects with multiple contributors.

Answer (score 2):

I just posted [Audit](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/audit) on Devot:ee. An add-on that tracks additional activity in the Control Panel, including entry deletes.